# Read file with 2 columns, rsync each line from column 1 to column 2

Tags: bash, shell-script, rsync

I have a file that has 2 columns. Column 1 has the source directory, Column 2 has the destination. For example:

```
$ cat directories.txt

/usr/local/myapp /root/myapp_bak
/home/steve/dir1 /root/stevedir
/etc/etc/etc /another/destination
```

I'm trying to write a short script/one liner that will read that file, and `rsync` column1 to column2 only by line. For example, it will read `directories.txt` then do the following:

```
rsync -va /usr/local/myapp /root/myapp_bak
rsync -va /home/steve/dir1 /root/stevedir
```

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Do your file and directory names contain any spaces?

Answer (score 8):

This might help you,

```
while IFS=' ' read -r source dest
do 
    rsync -av "$source" "$dest"
done <directories.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
< directories.txt xargs -n 2 rsync -va
```

Comment: or `xargs -d'\n' rsync …`